# Creating an Flat XML file from my DB schema for DBUnit initialization throws an exception

Tags: dbunit

Im trying to use DBUnit and set up an XML file for my schema (empty) so that I can use it with my DBUnit @DatabaseSetup annotation. I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, gdfp_key, gdfp_value, min_value, max_value from gdfp_condition_mappin' at line 1
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:323)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseTableIterator.getTable(DatabaseTableIterator.java:89)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.stream.DataSetProducerAdapter.produce(DataSetProducerAdapter.java:83)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlWriter.write(FlatXmlWriter.java:124)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet.write(FlatXmlDataSet.java:378)
    at com.wfx.common.hsqldb.DatabaseToHSQLXml.main(DatabaseToHSQLXml.java:40)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, gdfp_key, gdfp_value, min_value, max_value from gdfp_condition_mappin' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2758)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1612)
    at org.dbunit.database.AbstractResultSetTable.<init>(AbstractResultSetTable.java:110)
    at org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable.<init>(ForwardOnlyResultSetTable.java:59)
    at org.dbunit.database.CachedResultSetTableFactory.createTable(CachedResultSetTableFactory.java:60)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:319)
    ... 5 more
```

My database table looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gdfp_condition_mapping`;
CREATE TABLE `gdfp_condition_mapping` (
  `gdfp_condition_mapping_id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `condition` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gdfp_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gdfp_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_value` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_value` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gdfp_condition_mapping_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And my code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Class driverClass = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hsqldb", "hsqldbuser", "hsqldbuser");

    IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);

    // full database export
    IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();
    FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("DB_full.xml"));

}
```

Any ideas folks?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening since 'condition' is a reserved keyword. Changing that to 'condition_name' worked.